# Integrate over FindRoot solutions

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I have a function of bivariate normal PDF and its marginals defined as

```
f[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {x}]
f2[x_, y_] := 
  PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, ρ}, {ρ, 1}}], {x, y}] /. {ρ -> 1/2}
```

The function `fw` is quite complex so I solve it numerically using `FindRoot` for given `X0` and `Y0`.

```
fw[X0_?NumericQ, Y0_?NumericQ] := 
   Y /. 
     FindRoot[
       Integrate[f2[X0, u], {u, -∞, Y0}]f[X0] == Integrate[f2[X0, u], {u, -∞, Y}], 
       {Y, Y0}]
```

I would like to calculate the expected value of the function `fw` over the Gaussian curve but for a reason this doesn't work.

```
NIntegrate[fw[XD, YD] f2[XD, YD], {XD, -∞, ∞}, {YD, -∞, ∞}]
```

I suppose `NIntegrate` is either too slow or it cannot supply numerical values to `fw`. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Because `Integrate[f2[X0, u], {u,-Infinity, Y0}]` yields an analytic answer, replace it by that answer in `FindRoot` to save a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

As [@bbgodfrey commented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104261/integrate-over-findroot-solutions#comment282957_104261), if the integrals in the equation in the OP's `FindRoot` command can be evaluated before passing the equation to `FindRoot`, one can save a lot of time.  It seems there is still more to be done.  I found `FindRoot` struggles to find an accurate root in some areas of the domain of the equation.  It turns out one can use `Solve` to solve the equation and avoid `FindRoot` altogether.

```
fwEQ = Integrate[f2[X0, u], {u, -Infinity, Y0}] f[X0] ==
  Integrate[f2[X0, u], {u, -Infinity, Y}];
fwII[X0_, Y0_] = Y /. First@Solve[fwEQ, Y]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
(*  1/2 (X0 -Sqrt[6] InverseErfc[(E^(-(X0^2/2)) Erfc[(X0 - 2 Y0)/Sqrt[6]])/Sqrt[2 π]])  *)
```

The warning perhaps calls for some numerical checks:

```
With[{range = Join[-Reverse@#, {0}, #] &[2^Range[10]]},
   Table[
    fwEQ /. Equal -> Subtract /. {X0 -> x, Y0 -> y} /. Y -> fwII[x, y],
    {x, range}, {y, range}]
   ] // Abs // Max
(*  0  *)
```

The solution seems valid, so time to integrate.

*Mathematica* does not return an exact solution using `Integrate`, so we'll resort to a numerical approximation:

```
NIntegrate[fwII[XD, YD] f2[XD, YD], {XD, -Infinity, Infinity}, {YD, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(*  -1.08854  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact, I have tried Solve function and it worked well as you indicated. However, I have several more complicated equations to be solved which Solve function doesn't handle. This is why I tried to experiment with FindRoot which is quite slow together with NIntegrate.